# Is there a CSS layout that can reverse the arrangement of columns in a stack of rows for desktop view? (see image)

Tags: html, css, layout, bootstrap-4

[This image shows how I am trying to arrange](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYOIb.png) 
I am new to HTML and CSS. I am trying to arrange the desktop and mobile layouts to be ordered differently. Currently I am using the following code:

```
<div class="row ">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <img src="img/services/service1.jpg" alt=">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <h2> Service 1</h2>
        <p>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row ">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <img src="img/services/service2.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <h2> Service 2</h2>
        <p>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row ">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <img src="img/services/service3.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <h2> Service 3</h2>
        <p>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

This arranges the layout of elements as:

1,2

3,4

5,6

and I want to be:

1,2

4,3

5,6

Any help will be greatly appreciated :)

EDIT: But I want it to remain 1,2,3,4,5,6 on the phone. hence I am not swapping 3 and 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boostrap 4 uses the grid system based on flexbox which allows [reordering](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Ordering_Flex_Items). Check [reordering](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#reordering) section in bootstarp documentation for more details.

It may look like this:

```
<div class="row ">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <img src="img/services/service1.jpg" alt=">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <h2> Service 1</h2>
        <p>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row ">
    <div class="col-lg-6 order-sm-12">
        <img src="img/services/service2.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 order-sm-1">
        <h2> Service 2</h2>
        <p>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row ">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <img src="img/services/service3.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <h2> Service 3</h2>
        <p>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```